# ruby uniq on the first two columns of two dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a two dimensional array with three fields in the second dimension.

Is it possible to use uniq on the first two fields of the second dimension?

I have seen array.uniq! {|c| c.first}. When I am correct, this apply uniq on the first field of the array.

Is it possible to use something like array.uniq! {|c| c.first c.second}?

@array = Array.new()

@array << Array.new([journal.from_account_number, journal.from_account,
                                journal.buchungsart])
There are several entries in @array.

The question was how to get unique values from array not considering journal.buchungsart.

The answer was: @array = @array.uniq! {|c| [c.first, c.second]}

Comment: Your question begs for an example. When you give an example, 1. all inputs must be valid Ruby objects (no `[1,2,3...]`, for example;) 2) show the desired output, also as a valid Ruby object; 3) assign a variable to each input object (`arr = [1,2,3]`) so readers can refer to those variables without having to define them in answers and comments; and 4) make the example as brief as possible but still convey the essential elements of the question. Please consider editing the question to provide an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, put the values in an array:

```
array.uniq! {|c| [c.first, c.second]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return an array of two elements in the block.

Since `Array#second` is not defined in the standard library, do

```
array.uniq! { |c| [c[0], c[1]] }
```

instead, which can be further simplified to `array.uniq! { |c| c[0..1] }`

Answer (score 2):

You could also make use of the fact that hash keys are unique.

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 5]]

a = arr.each_with_object({}) { |row, h| h.update(row.first(2)=>row) }.values
  #=> [[1, 2, 5], [2, 1, 4]]
```

See [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`).

Before extracting the hash values with [Hash#value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values), we have computed the following hash.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |row, h| h.update(row.first(2)=>row) }
  #=> {[1, 2]=>[1, 2, 5], [2, 1]=>[2, 1, 4]}
```

Notice that, for given values of the first two elements in a row, it is the last row of `arr` with those values that is to be "kept". The first such row in `arr` is to be kept, use the following.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |row, h| h.update(row.first(2)=>row) { |_,o,_| o } }.values
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4]]
```

This does not mutate `arr`. If `arr` is to be modified, write

```
arr.replace(a)
```

where `a` is defined above.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) accepts a parameter :

```
%w(a b c d e f).first(2)
# => ["a", "b"]
```

so you could just use :

```
array.uniq!{ |c| c.first(2) }
```